# How would I create a flowing, gradually turning UV Map for a model? (Have pictures)

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, geometry, procedural

I am trying to learn how to do more complex UV-Mapping techniques, and have been running into trouble here. I'm not sure how to unfold/texture these sections (It's a zebra) Where the pattern gradually turns and changes like so.

Do I just have to do it the hard way, and meticulously plan it out? Do some hand-done texture painting?

Looking online, a fair bit of models have this same issue, even ones in modern professional games, so I assume it's not an easy answer. Any guides or links explaining how to do this sort of flowing, gradually changing UV Map stuff would be appreciated, or examples of course. Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Well, there are multiple possible answers here.

First off, UV seams don't dictate your texturing. You can take your photo, paint it directly onto your seams (using *Stencil* projection in Blender's Texture Paint mode), and it will look fine. You can clean it up or paint over afterwards.
[image: texture paint]
Using a photo is, of course, optional. All the tools work across seams.

Second. If the seams, for whatever reason, are a problem, you can unwrap it like a pelt instead, hiding all seams out of sight as much as possible.
[image: pelt unwrap]

Third. The [natural pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patterns_in_nature#Spots,_stripes) that a zebra exhibits is known as "reaction diffusion" (or a "Turing pattern"). There are plugins to emulate it for various graphical applications, and a node in Substance Designer.
[image: reaction diffusion]

Said node can be used to make a simple filter for Substance Painter. Note that a filter operates in UV space, so this is a good showcase of the advantages of pelt-style unwrap.
[image: painter filter]

Comment: Wow. Well, that's 2 features I didn't know existed that seem perfect for the task. What a powerful piece of software. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Do you know of any equivalent ways to perform this filter-style texture generation in Blender?

Comment: The filter works by repeatedly subtracting a blurred image from the original. Blender lacks a blur node, and the common workaround (distorting texture coordinates with noise) won't work here, as it doesn't actually produce a gradient. Best you can do is draw the same basic lines in Blender, then save the texture out and filter it using GIMP/Photoshop/what have you.

Comment: Isn't this a blur node for Blender right here in their documentation? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/blur_node.html

Comment: It's for compositing (i.e. post processing a rendered frame), while we would want one for shading. I guess technically you could use the compositor as a makeshift image editor, but it would be highly impractical.

Comment: Well, the only method that seems viable involves giving Adobe a fortune. Not what I was hoping for on the blender stackexchange.

Comment: [GIMP is free.](https://i.imgur.com/IdAdDeS.mp4) (Filters > G'MIC > Patterns > Stencil)